# Linker Error while using openssl

Tags: c, linker, openssl

I have the openssl folder here:

```
C:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl
```

In dev c++ I gave the following to the linker command line:

```
-lssl -lcrypto -l<C:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl>
```

and the following to when it calls the compiler:

```
-L<C:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl>
```

After compilation the dev c++ shows this error:

```
cannot find -l<C:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl> 
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `-l<C:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl>` from you link line command.

```
-lssl -lcrypto
```

you have already linked to the openssl library with `-lssl -lcrypto`

If you want to specify the path where the library are saved. you have to use only

```
-L<C:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl>
```

Comment: ...and I suspect that `<` and `>` should be removed

Comment: I did as you said but now here comes the error:
[Linker error] undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
[Linker error] undefined reference to `AES_encrypt' 
ld returned 1 exit status @MOHAMED

Comment: did your tried to rmove the `<` and the `>` from the path like this `-LC:\Dev-Cpp\include\openssl`

Comment: may be your path should looks like this `-LC:\\Dev-Cpp\\include\\openssl`